# Can't get li inline

Tags: html, css, menu, inline

I'm trying to make a horizontal navi menu.
I want to get the logo and then the parts of the menu but the inline doesn't work.

I wanted the images above the text so I used a table to get this, but this broke the inline effect.. I'd be greatful for any help

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TechSocket</title>

  <style>
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90%;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #000;
    }
    #nav {
      display: inline;
      background-color: #CF6;
      position: fixed;
      padding: 1%;
      width: 97%;
    }
    ul {
      diplay: inline;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0%;
    }
    #nav li {
      display: inline;
    }
    #logo {
      padding-left: 0%;
    }
    table {
      border-spacing: 25px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="headIMG" href="#"><img id="logo" src="100-Beanie-Drive-Logo-250.jpg" width="250" height="100"/></a><li>
    <li>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#" class="text"><img id="text1"src="mouse.png" width="50" height="50"/></a></td>
          <td><a href="#" class="text"><img id="text2" src="cam.png" width="50" height="50"/></a></td>
          <td><a href="#" class="text"><img id="text3"src="cloud.png" width="50" height="50"/></a></td>
          <td><a href="#" class="text"><img id="text4"src="clock.png" width="50" height="50"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mouse</td>
          <td>Camera</td>
          <td>Cloud</td>
          <td>Clock</td>
        </tr>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try floating it to the left, like so:

```
#nav li {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to have this line for your ul

`diplay: inline;`

Alternatively you can use `display:inline-block`, which might suit your needs better.

li elements are block elements so inline probably doesn't work with them, especially when they have other elements inside them. I'm just guessing though, never actually tested it.

As for floating, well personally I'd be against it. I've always found it to cause issues when not used properly. That said, it is a possible fix.